# IntelliJ PHP fluent setter intention

Tags: php, intellij-idea

Right now IntelliJ with PHP plugin supports setter/getter intention in following way (`Settings > Intentions > PHP > Add setter`):

Before:

```
<?php
class Sample
{
    private $index;
}
```

After:

```
<?php
class Sample
{
    private $index;

    public function setIndex($index)
    {
        $this->index = $index;
    }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to create fluent setters like described below ?

```
<?php
class Sample
{
    private $index;

    public function setIndex($index)
    {
        $this->index = $index;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.
Go to: Settings > File and Code Templates > Code (tab) > PHP Setter Method.
Add "return $this;" like in my example.

```
/**
 * @param ${TYPE_HINT} $${PARAM_NAME}
 * @return $this
 */
public ${STATIC} function set${NAME}($${PARAM_NAME})
{
#if (${STATIC} == "static")
    self::$${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
#else
    $this->${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
    return $this;
#end
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works like a charm. I've also added `@return $this` PHPDoc in your answer.